# Can't get document.execCommand("copy") to work as expected

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to scrape some data off a page and can't quite get `document.execCommand("copy")` to work as expected.

As a test, I am injecting some HTML into the page and then try to copy it to the clipboard

`$('#topcard h1').append('<a id="getData" type="text">This is some data</a>')`

I can then see `This is some data` on the page appear

Then:

```
var copyText = document.querySelector("#getData")
copyText
```

Shows in the console:
`<a id=​"getData" type=​"text">​This is some data​</a>​`

It seems that `copyText` is exactly what I want it to be.

However:
`copyText.select()`
returns

```
VM2319:1 Uncaught TypeError: copyText.select is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:10
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's not how to create a text [selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection).  You need to create a Selection, add a Range to it, and set the Range boundaries.

Comment: @DanielBeck Thank you for that info. I'm going off of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard What is the difference between my code and their example?

Comment: Their example happens *after* you create the text selection.  Select it first using Range etc, then use execCommand("copy") to copy it to the clipboard.

Comment: (Oh, wait, now I'm seeing their example under "Using execCommand()".  I don't know what's going on there with .select() -- I may be missing something here)

Comment: ok. I'm new to development, and will try to figure out how to add a range! Thank you

Comment: Ah, got it: `.select()` is for input fields or textareas (but not contenteditable nodes as @enxaneta suggested); if you need to select other text in a page, that needs Ranges etc.  Sorry, I should've spotted that in the first place

Comment: Oooh, got it. Ok. Thanks!

Comment: ftwiw, I injected an `<input .. />`, set it to something using `.val()`, then copied it using `.select()` and it works as expected. if you put your comment as an answer i'll mark it as right

Comment: Done!  I should have done that in the first place, I suppose -- have a bad habit of answering questions in comments for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.select()` will let you set the selection range for an `<input>` or `<textarea>`:

```js
document.getElementById("foo").select()
```

```html
<input id="foo" value="12345">
```

...but will not work for other DOM nodes (including contentEditable nodes).  To select anything other than a form field's contents, you need to use the [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) API:

```js
var r = document.createRange();
r.selectNode(document.getElementById("foo"));
var s = window.getSelection();
s.addRange(r);
```

```html
<div id="foo">12345</div>
```

In either case, once the selection is made you can then use `document.execCommand("copy")` to capture the selected text to the clipboard -- but with one very important caveat:  this must be done within a user-initiated event handler.  (This is to prevent malicious websites from hijacking the user's clipboard without their knowledge.)

```js
var captureSelection = function() {
  var r = document.createRange();
  r.selectNode(document.getElementById("foo"));
  var s = window.getSelection();
  s.addRange(r);
  document.execCommand("copy");
}

// this will select the DOM node, but will  not copy it to 
// the clipboard (because it's not user-initiated):
captureSelection();

// this _will_ copy it to the clipboard:
document.getElementById("bar").onclick = captureSelection;
```

```html
<div id="foo">12345</div>

<button id="bar">Go</button>
<br><br>

<textarea placeholder="paste text here"></textarea>
```

Comment: wow, this is great. Thanks Daniel! I didn't quite grasp `.createRange()` but this makes it easy to understand